# jQuery - Uncheck other checkboxes if a specific checkbox is selected by user

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I would like to uncheck all the checkboxes that are presently selected if a specific checkbox is selected by the user.

Example:

```
<div>
    <label for="foo">
        <input type="checkbox" name="meh" id="foo" checked> foo
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="bar">
        <input type="checkbox" name="meh" id="bar" checked> bar
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="foobar">
        <input type="checkbox" name="meh" id="foobar"> foobar
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="barfoo">
        <input type="checkbox" name="meh" id="barfoo" checked> barfoo
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="omgwtfbbq">
        <input type="checkbox" name="meh" id="omgwtfbbq"> omgwtfbbq
    </label>
</div>
```

If the user selects "omgwtfbbq" checkbox, I would like all the other boxes that might be checked to be unchecked and have the "omgwtfbbq" be the only one checked.

Comment: Hey all, I fixed the issue with the name="" not being consistent and I fixed the for="" so it was not id="" (D'Oh!!!!)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for the `label` instead of `id` I think you need `for`

```
<div>
    <label for="foo">
        <input type="checkbox" name="foo" id="foo" checked /> foo
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="bar">
        <input type="checkbox" name="bar" id="bar" checked /> bar
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="foobar">
        <input type="checkbox" name="foobar" id="foobar" /> foobar
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="barfoo">
        <input type="checkbox" name="barfoo" id="barfoo" checked /> barfoo
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="omgwtfbbq">
        <input type="checkbox" name="omgwtfbbq" id="omgwtfbbq" /> omgwtfbbq
    </label>
</div>
```

then

```
var $others = $('input[type="checkbox"][name="meh"]').not('#omgwtfbbq')
$('#omgwtfbbq').change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $others.prop('checked', false)
    }
});
$others.change(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#omgwtfbbq').prop('checked', false)
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5q27p/)

Note: I'll add a common class to all the input elements which has to be affected by `omgwtfbbq` and change `var $others = $('#foo, #bar, #foobar, #barfoo')` to `var $others = $('.myclassoninput')`

Comment: And this is the winner!

Comment: But then you have to manually list all the IDs. What if a new checkbox is added to the mix?

Comment: @Schien just to show how the checkboxes to be selected... need to fine tune it based on the OPs need...

Comment: @Schien that's because the OP doesn't have a parent element to select them by in the included markup. That being, this is the only way to be sure you're not selecting things that shouldn't be selected.

Comment: I see. My solution is ID agnostic and self-reflecting.

Comment: I updated my question to have proper for="" and now proper name=""  My bad everybody.

Comment: @m59 understood. If you have control over the markup I'd recommend you add that container. You'll likely need it for styling anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/aTOPAseC/3/edit)**

```
$('#omgwtfbbq').click(function() {
  $('input:checkbox').not(this).attr('checked', false);
});
```

Also note that you're re-using id's. Id's should only be used once in a document.

Answer (score 0):

If you choose not to give each checkbox a sequential IDs so that you can use an array, here's a solution:

Place all your controls in a div, with an ID "checkgroup".

Then the JavaScript function goes:

```
function checkone(d){
  if (!d.checked) return; //if it's unchecked, then do nothing

  var group=document.getElementById('checkgroup');
  var os=group.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var i=0;i<os.length;i++){

    if (os[i].checked&&os[i]!=d) os[i].checked=false;

  }

}
```

Now you can call this function in each checkbox

```
<div id="checkgroup">
  <input id="abcd" onclick="checkone(this);">
  <input id="xyz" onclick="checkone(this);">
  ...
</div>
```

Note how you don't even need to bother with the name, because the object passes in itself.