# Javascript - unselect checkboxes, items mutually exclusive

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a group of check boxes that are all part of one array. What I require is that if the first one is selected (I don't mind), then any of the others are unselected, and vice versa - if one of the bottom three options are selected, then I don't mind needs to be unselected.
The last three options can all be selected at the same time.

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21248737/jquery-uncheck-other-checkboxes-if-a-specific-checkbox-is-selected-by-user) is similar to what I am asking to do. Any help would be appreciated

```
<fieldset class="checkbox">
    <legend>Sitter type</legend>
    <div id="field_844" class="input-options checkbox-options">
        <label for="field_1071_0" class="option-label">
            <input  type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1071_0" value="I don&#039;t mind">I don&#039;t mind</label>
        <label for="field_1072_1" class="option-label">
            <input  checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1072_1" value="Sitter">Sitter</label>
        <label for="field_1073_2" class="option-label">
            <input  type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1073_2" value="Nanny">Nanny</label>
        <label for="field_1074_3" class="option-label">
            <input  type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1074_3" value="Au Pair">Au Pair</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Please post your js/jquery code.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using radio buttons for this instead of check boxes (other than appearance)

Comment: @dandavis: Welp maybe I should read the question fully :/

Comment: to avoid nested combo flow, i would set a change handler on the first one that unchecks the last 3 if checked, and another handler on the last 3 that unchecks the first if checked.

Comment: Maybe, Brett asks for a general solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is exactly the same as the link you provided.

```
<fieldset class="checkbox">
    <legend>Sitter type</legend>
    <div id="field_844" class="input-options checkbox-options">
        <label for="field_1071_0" class="option-label">
            <input  type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1071_0" value="I don&#039;t mind">I don&#039;t mind</label>
        <label for="field_1072_1" class="option-label">
            <input  checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1072_1" value="Sitter">Sitter</label>
        <label for="field_1073_2" class="option-label">
            <input  type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1073_2" value="Nanny">Nanny</label>
        <label for="field_1074_3" class="option-label">
            <input  type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1074_3" value="Au Pair">Au Pair</label>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

And then:

```
// We cache all the inputs except `#field_1071_0` with `:not` pseudo-class
var $target = $('input:not(#field_1071_0)');


$('#field_1071_0').on('change', function () {

    // if 'i don't mind' is selected.
    if (this.checked) {     
       // remove the 'checked' attribute from the rest checkbox inputs.
        $target.prop('checked', false);
    }
});

$target.on('change', function () {
    // if one of the bottom three options are selected
    if (this.checked) {  
        // then I don't mind needs to be unselected
        $('#field_1071_0').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/426qLkrn/4/

Comment: Upvoting, but just a suggestion to make Your code look nicer: add `var $target =$('#field_1071_0');` and then use it in `$target.on(..` and `$target.prop(...`

Comment: Ivor, this works, but I need to limit it to the div that is in the code, there are other checkbox arrays on my form.

Comment: Sorry for the double post, missed the editing timeframe! $others needs to be limited to just those items listed in the code, and not every other input on the form

Comment: @Brett Canfield, change `$others` to this: `var $others = $('div#field_844 input:not(#field_1071_0)');`

Comment: @BrettCanfield If this answer was the one that helped you remember to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) ;)

Comment: @BrettCanfield, I'm glad it's been helpful.

Comment: @Ivor, It appears to be some ambiguity in my suggestion above. So, to clear things up, here is the [code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/jbsnytk2/2/).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot remember an in-house feature of JavaScript or jQuery that makes it possible to solve your problem. So, you have to solve it by your own.

You can add a `data` attribute to your checkboxes where you list all the checkboxes (as an id) which cannot be selected at the same time with the current checkbox, e.g.:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1071_0" value="I don&#039;t mind" data-exclude="['field_1072_1','field_1072_2','field_1072_3']" />
<input checked="checked" type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1072_1" value="Sitter" data-exclude="['field_1071_0']" />
...
```

Then, you add, for example, an `onchange` event to each of the checkboxes. This event checks whether the checkbox has changed to checked or to unchecked. If it has changed to checked, you have to uncheck all checkboxes within the list:

```
document.getElementById("field_1071_0").onchange= function(e) {
    if (this.checked) {
         this.dataset.exclude.forEach(function (exc) {
            document.getElementById(exc).checked = false;
         });
    }
};
```

Or, with jQuery:

```
$("#field_1071_0").change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).data('exclude').forEach(function (exc) {
            $("#" + exc).prop("checked", false);
        });
    }
});
```

The good thing is: You can apply this function to each checkbox you want, e.g.:

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function (e) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).data('exclude').forEach(function (exc) {
            $("#" + exc).prop("checked", false);
        });
    }
});
```

Now, each checkbox has the desired behaviour. So, this solution is a general way to solve it.

Comment: If you do not have access to the HTML code, i.e., to the input fields to add some information like the data-attribute, you can add those information via jQuery/JavaScript too:

```
$("#field_1071_0").data("exclude", ['field_1072_1','field_1072_2','field_1072_3']);
$("#field_1072_1").data("exclude", ['field_1071_0']);
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, makes the most sense to me, but I am not in control of the creation of the checkboxes, so I am reluctant to add in the extra code in at this time. Still going to upvote, as for many, this would be the best way to achieve it.

Comment: That make sense... But you can add the data information with jQuery to the input fields ;): `$("#field_1071_0").data("exclude", ['field_1072_1','field_1072_2','field_1072_3']);`

Comment: I'm still new to the javascript/jquery game, any help is appreciated, thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

jquery [**prop**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method can be used to pragmatically check or unchecked a check box. [**is**](http://api.jquery.com/is/) can be use to evaluate if a condition is true or false.

Hope this snippet will be useful

```js
// if first check box is selected , then checkedremaining three
$("#field_1071_0").on('change', function() {
   //$(this) is the check box with id field_1071_0
   // checking if first checkbox is checked
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    //opt2 is a common class for rest of the check boxes
    // it will uncheck all other checkbox
    $(".opt2").prop('checked', false)
  }
})
//unchecking first checkbox when any of the rest check box is checked
$(".opt2").on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    $("#field_1071_0").prop('checked', false)
  }
})
```

```html
<!--Adding a class `opt2` to the last three checkboxes-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset class="checkbox">
  <legend>Sitter type</legend>
  <div id="field_844" class="input-options checkbox-options">
    <label for="field_1071_0" class="option-label">
      <input type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1071_0" value="I don&#039;t mind">I don&#039;t mind</label>
    <label for="field_1072_1" class="option-label">
      <input checked="checked" type="checkbox" class="opt2" name="field_844[]" id="field_1072_1" value="Sitter">Sitter</label>
    <label for="field_1073_2" class="option-label">
      <input type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" class="opt2" id="field_1073_2" value="Nanny">Nanny</label>
    <label for="field_1074_3" class="option-label">
      <input type="checkbox" name="field_844[]" id="field_1074_3" value="Au Pair" class="opt2">Au Pair</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```